# Čech cohomology and sheaf cohomology

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $X.$ It is clear to me that $\check{H^{0}}(X,\mathcal{F})=H^{0}(X,\mathcal{F}).$ It is also true that $\check{H^{1}}(X,\mathcal{F})=H^{1}(X,\mathcal{F})$ (Harthshorne, exe. III.4.4). But what about higher cohomology groups?

I belive that for $k\geq2$ it is false in general that $\check{H^{k}}(X,\mathcal{F})=H^{k}(X,\mathcal{F})$ but I don't know how to construct a counterexample. Is there a well known example of such $X$ and $\mathcal{F}?$  I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Also note Exercise III 4.11, which tells you that they agree, if $\mathcal{F}$ does not have cohomology on any set of the form $U_{i_1} \cap \dotsc \cap U_{i_n}$.

Comment: @red_trumpet this is why it is hard to find a counter example since most of "nice" topological spaces will satisfy this for some covering